# Application incompatibility

Tags: music-player

I recently tried to install microsoft groove but the play store said, this app is incompatible with your device which is strange because. Im using Android 5.0.1 with all the latest updates.

Is there a way around this.

Comment: Which device you using same with me. May be there is location based compatibility etc.

Comment: Im using Infinix-X551

Comment: Most of the time when it says its incompatible with your device  its because of the OS i remember i got that alot back in the jelly bean days... If its the location it just says this isnt avaliable in your country

Comment: I have a device with 5.1 and now how recent i can be.

Comment: Is it the same if you try side loading?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I did some digging, you can download the app from [Aptoide](https://groove.en.aptoide.com/) or you can use a better app called [CloudPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.cloudPlayer&hl=en).